# Мальчики избалованы. Сколько Н?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, причастия

Мальчики избалова(Н/НН)ы. Сколько Н? Как мне видится, это один из тех случаев, где правописание факультативно. Формально это все же прилагательное (по аналогии с "воспитанный"), оно занесено в словари, в частности, как прилагательное. Но... одно Н тут сама так и просится, как ни крути. Да и на практике двойную Н встретишь редко, в Нацкорпусе соотношение Н/НН — 147/4. А что вы думаете по поводу правописания этого словосочетания? Заранее премного благодарен!

Comment: Ну, в контексте "однородных прилагательных", можно нн: Мальчики непослушны и избалованны. А так да, в основном одна н.

Answer (score 2):

*Избалованный* может быть как страдательным причастием, так и произошедшим от него прилагательным. В полной форме пишется *нн* в обоих случаях.

В краткой же форме, написание различается:

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §100. Краткие формы страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишутся с одним *н*.
>
> §101. Краткие формы (кроме формы мужского рода) прилагательных с качественным значением, совпадающих по форме со страдательными причастиями прошедшего времени глаголов совершенного вида, пишутся с *нн*.
>
> Такие прилагательные имеют формы сравнительной степени.
>
> **Ср. попарно следующие примеры с краткими формами причастий и прилагательных: *Она избалована хорошими условиями.* — *Она капризна и избалованна.***

Поэтому написание в вашем примере зависит от того, причастие это или прилагательное, а это крайне сложно определить без контекста.

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что по-разному писать можно.

*Мальчики избалованы бабушкой (краткое причастие).

Мальчики избалованны (краткое прилагательное).*